# Candlestick chart shadows not showing black

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this code to display a candlestick chart. For "test2" the body color and the border color are working but the shadow color is not. I call the shadows the vertical lines at the top and the bottom that show the high and low points if they are above or below the body. (They are still showing in yellow, as below)  Accorrding to a book I have they are called Shadowsnd have used "Shadowcolor", does C# call them something else?

```
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace PlotCharts
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random rdn = new Random();

            chart1.Series["test1"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Candlestick;
            chart1.Series["test1"].Color = Color.Red;
            chart1.Series["test1"].BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

            chart1.Series["test2"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Candlestick;
            chart1.Series["test2"].BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            chart1.Series["test2"].ShadowColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            chart1.Series["test2"].Color = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;


            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                chart1.Series["test1"].Points.AddXY(i,4.5,4,3);
                chart1.Series["test2"].Points.AddXY(2.5,6,9,7,8);
            }




        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, c# doesn't call them **anything** - this is a library/framework question - but : have you looked up the type in question on MSDN? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456671.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
chart1.Series["test2"].Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
```

instead of

```
chart1.Series["test2"].ShadowColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
```